# Any project publish in code but an error occurs. How do i solve?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

```
    public Foo()
    {
        PublishProject();
    }

    internal static void PublishProject()
    {
        var project = GetActiveProject();
        var sb2 = project.DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild as SolutionBuild2;
        sb2.PublishProject(project.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.ConfigurationName, project.UniqueName, true);
    }

       internal static EnvDTE.Project GetActiveProject()
       {
           EnvDTE.DTE dte = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SDTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
           EnvDTE.Project activeProject = null;
           string endWith = ((dte.Solution.SolutionBuild as EnvDTE80.SolutionBuild2).StartupProjects as System.Array).GetValue(0).ToString();
           foreach (EnvDTE.Project project in dte.Solution.Projects)
           {
               if (project.FullName != null && project.FullName.EndsWith(endWith))
               {
                   return project;
               }
           }
           return null;
       }
```

Output :

1>------ Publish started: Project: WebApplication2, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------

1>Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Note : I translated it using translate.

i publish web appliction project (.net freamwork) in code.

i look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.solutionbuild2.publishproject?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

i used this method but the error it gives does not make any sense.

Is there anything missing in the question?

Could you help

Comment: This doesnt help at all. You dont describe the problem, dont tell us what you already tried and it doesnt even show what you are trying to accomplish in an understandable manner. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Dont expect the community to just look at it and give you an answer.

Comment: The problem is stated: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. If unfortunately, I dont understand to which object this applies. You need to make sure your object references are valid and not `null` before you can use them.

Comment: I debugged Any value is not empty then would give an exception. gives the error on the output screen.

Comment: Did you face any other error when you build your project? It seems that it failed in publishing the project. I wonder how you imported the related sdk apis in a net framework web project. Besides, please share the current cs file with us.

Answer (score 1):

> Any project publish in code but an error occurs. How do i solve?

From your description, not only this project but also other projects have the publish issue.

If you install [Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK/) nuget package and then reference these assemblies:

```
using EnvDTE80;
using EnvDTE;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
```

I will not face the same publish error in my side with your code. So I think there is some errors in your project environment or VS IDE.

Please try these suggestions:

**Suggestion**

**1)** delete all component caches under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxx(15.0 is VS2019)\ComponentModelCache` and then restart VS

**2)** disable any third party extensions under `Tools`-->`Extensions and Updates`.

**3)** delete `*.dll.refresh` file in the **bin** output folder if you have.

**4)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin`, `obj` folder and then restart your project.

**5)** Please check you have McAfee anti-virus and if so, please turn off it.

**6)** If your VS2017 is not the latest version, please update it in case some fixes or [do a repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Hope it could help you.